# Compare two list in list, if list b index[x] in a do something

Tags: python, list

I have two list like this (for example) :

```
a = [['1','2'],['3','4'],['5','6','7']]
b = [['1'],['3','4'],['5','6'],['7']]

If b in a : #in this case is(['3','4']) 
    print 'same'
    #stop
else:
    print 'its different'
```

I already do this in my code :

```
for x in b:
    if x in a:
        print 'same', x
        break
    else:
        print 'its different', x
```

I generate about 100 list, when the results are different (else) the process continues looping as len of b.

**I just want if the result same, stop and when its different just print and continue to check next list.**

When i break if and else statement, or just break the else statementits affect the end of result

**EDIT**

100 list

```
a = [['1','2'],['3','4'],['5','6','7']]
b = [['1'],['3','4'],['5','6'],['7']]
c = [['5','6','7'],['2']]
d = [['3'],['8']]
e = [[...],[...]]
azz = [[...],[...]]
for x in b:
    if x in a:
        print 'same ==', x
        #break
    else:
        print 'its different', x
        #break
```

**result**

```
different b ==  ['1']
same b == ['3', '4']
different b ==  ['5', '6']
different b ==  ['7']
```

**continue**

```
same c ==  ['5', '6', '7']
different c ==  ['2']
```

**continue**

```
different d ==  ['3']
different d ==  ['8']
```

**continue to list 100**

**i want the result like this :**

```
same b == ['3', '4']
#the result stop because its same and ignored the different result
```

**continue**

```
same c ==  ['5', '6', '7']
#the result stop because its same and ignored the different result
```

**continue**

```
different d ==  ['3']
#the result stop BECAUSE ITS DIFFERENT AND IGNORED THE SAME RESULT
```

**continue to list 100**

Comment: So, what's the problem with second code?

Comment: When x in a is not same, 'else' contiunes looping as len of b.
I want the else statement print and stop

Comment: Add `break` after `print` in `else`. Do you want to print `same` when `a` and `b` be the same completely?

Comment: if i add a `break` after `print` in `else`, the code affect to my if statement.
e.g : 100 list have 70 `same` condition.
when i add `break` after `print` in `else`, result of 'same' not 70 but < 70.
if i add `break` after `print` in `if` statement, result of `else` statement continue looping as len of b and the result of 'same' is 70 but result of `different` > 30

Comment: I'm sorry. It seems that isn't necessary any `break`. If this doesn't work so I don't understand what you want. Please add your expected output for sample in question.

Comment: `a = [['1','2'],['3','4'],['5','6','7']]
b = [['1'],['3','4'],['5','6'],['7']]

for x in b:
 if x in a:
  print 'same == ', x
  #break
 else:
  print 'different == ', x`

Result :

`different ==  ['1']
same ==  ['3', '4']
different ==  ['5', '6']
different ==  ['7']`

i just want the result like this :

`same == ['3','4']`

Then if not same, result is:

`different == ['1']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a list of your lists like:

```
Lists = [b, c, d, ...]
```

And:

```
for item in Lists:

    flag = 0
    for x in item:
        if x in a:
            flag = 1
            print ('same ==', x)
            break

    if flag == 0:
        print('different ==', item[0])
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn work.
Because its double check b where b in a, not continue to next list (c,d,e, . . .)


_I have <= 100 list, i want `if same` its continue to check `list c`_

Comment: Thankyout, its work :)